# firefox-locale-en not removed after apt purge firefox

Tags: linux-mint, firefox, dependencies

I've just installed Linux Mint (Tara) on an old laptop. One of the first things I've done is removing Firefox using `sudo apt purge firefox` and installing Chromium.

Now, after doing `sudo apt autoremove`, `sudo apt autoclean` and `sudo apt update`, `apt` tells me that one of the packages that can be upgraded is `firefox-locale-en`. Shouldn't this package be removed when I unninstalled Firefox? Isn't `firefox-locale-en` a Firefox dependency?

Comment: "Isn't firefox-locale-en a Firefox dependency?" To answer that, run `apt depends firefox`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. According to the command it isn't but why? What other purpose could that package have if it is not to work only with firefox?.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that else I'd have posted an answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is no declared relationship, in Linux Mint, between the `firefox` package and the `firefox-locale-en` package; as a result, removing the former doesn’t result in the removal of the latter. It could make sense to have `firefox-locale-en` depend on `firefox` (the equivalent Debian packages do this); that way, removing `firefox` would force the removal of `firefox-locale-en`. Perhaps you could file a bug...